# How to properly pressurize gas pipes?

Tags: oxygen-not-included

I am attempting to cycle gases throughout my base but the vent keeps it is saying over pressurized. I have a gas valve connected to my pipe line to reduce the flow as low as possible yet it still says over-pressurized. The same applies when I have the flow set to anywhere up to max. Is there something I am missing?

I have not attempted to mess with rooms by closing them off with rooms that do not allow gas or liquid to flow freely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gas vent being overpressurized means the room you're trying to pump the air in (the tile the vent is at to be exact) already has too much gas in it. Currently however the game has a bug where the warning does not go away even when the vent is working fine. For the vent to really stop working due to being overpressurized (you will see the air starting to build up in the pipes and not going out) you need well above 2kg of gas in the room per tile.

Comment: Ah, I see how that works now. So the gas pipes are not for recirculating air in the base, but to transfer between air-locked areas.

Answer (score 2):

I think the over pressurisation is on the room side of the vent. Try venting bad air out of the room.

You can only jam so much air into a room without off venting.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to put more vents through the base, all connected to the main pump line. I have a vent that's only in about 100g pressure and it still says it's over pressurized, plus I have a valve. The other vents I installed off the main line are working fine.